# How to move only one cell of a column and keep other columns same

Tags: excel, powerquery

I hope someone can help me. Currently I have a table in which I need to move up or erase the first null of the last column only. This will let me to have all data in the same row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZTic.png)

I used conditional columns but I dont know how to refer the next row.

= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if [Column5] = null then **[Column5]** else 1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzLHI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This moves the rows up one in the last column.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
x = {List.Combine({List.RemoveFirstN(List.Last(Table.ToColumns(Source)),1),{null}})},
y = List.RemoveLastN(Table.ToColumns(Source),1),
custom = Table.FromColumns(List.Combine({y,x}),Table.ColumnNames(Source))
in custom
```

[image]

This adds a new column with the former last column shifted up one row

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
columnname=List.Last(Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
shiftedList =   List.RemoveFirstN(Table.Column(Source,columnname),1) & {null},
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Source) & {shiftedList},
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"ShiftedRow"})
in custom2
```

[image]

Comment: I actually need to create a new column with the data one row moved up. I tried including a index colum, but I dont know how to refer it the conditional column.

Comment: edited answer above to do that